# Passing PHP string to JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, php

I am having a issue while passing php string to JavaScript function. When i pass the numeric value it works fine. But when i pass the string it doesn't work

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function updateButton(custID, custEmail)
{
alert (custID);
alert (custEmail);
}
```

And this is my php code:

```
echo '<td><input id="btnUpdate" type="submit" name="btnUpdate" value = "Update" onclick="updateButton(' . $row['CustomerID']  . ',' .  $row['custEmail'] . ')" /> </td>';
```

In the above php code $row['CustomerID'] has the numeric value and $row['custEmail'] has the string value.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include a question :)

Comment: You have to be aware of the context your output will be used in. You're dumping text from PHP into a javascript-inside-html context. Your text is NAKED - no quotes around, so it'll be treated by JS as variable names or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
echo '<td><input id="btnUpdate" type="submit" name="btnUpdate" value = "Update" onclick="updateButton("' . $row['CustomerID']  . '","' .  $row['custEmail'] . '")" /> </td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around the string

```
echo '<td><input id="btnUpdate" type="submit" name="btnUpdate" value = "Update" onclick="updateButton(' . $row['CustomerID']  . ',\'' .  $row['custEmail'] . '\')" /> </td>';
```

Comment: If so, then accept his answer, that is the spirit of this website.